# JPA setup with EntityManager and MySQL database problems

Tags: mysql, spring, jpa, autowired

Ive been trying to set up a server that are going to expose some public web services. I do have a lot of problems when I try to @Autowire objects, and setup a connection with a MySQL database. When I fix one error, 10 new ones show up, but it seems like this EntityManager and EntityManagerFactory problem is the main error.

Ive tried both to deploy on a cloudfoundry server, and a local jetty server. On my local jetty server I get this error:

http://pastie.org/3282244

when my xml files (pom.xml, servlet-context.xml and persistence.xml) looks like this:

http://pastie.org/3282236

My User object implementation can be seen underneath the java error linked to above. (Couldnt use more than 2 links in a post)

The errors in general is about not being able to autowire fields, but as Ive understood it, this is because of the entitymanager problems. Am I right?
I might suspect that there are some version problems in the pom.xml file.

Any help is much appreciated, way to many days have gone now without any improvement!

Jon

Comment: We're not going to chase links around pastebin.  Paste the relevant bits of code and config into your question.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the entity manager is not configured right. This snippet works for me:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" id="transactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<!-- replace this with your data source -->
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="java:comp/env/jdbc/project" />

 <bean
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
    id="entityManagerFactory">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceUnit" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />

    <!-- this is important if you want to
         connect JPA and JdbcTemplate transaction control -->
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="false" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>


<!-- jdbc templates that are equal for all databases -- may not needed by you -->
<bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate" id="jdbcTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcTemplate" id="simpleJdbcTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
```

Then you can use (if you use Spring Autowireing)

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;
```